# Subscribtion in stripe payment gateway

Tags: android, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, subscription, recurring-billing

I want to use stripe android sdk pre build UI **payment sheet** for recurring payment (Subscription) in my android app.
I see payment sheet example for **non recurring payment** on stripe document but i didn't found document for **subscription in android**. I have spend lot of time to find example of same but i didn't get any solution.

If anyone help me then it's save my day.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that Stripe doesn't have a dedicated Doc for Subscription + PaymentSheet.

However you should be able to follow their general [Subscription integration guide](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements), but in [step 6 of "Collect payment information"](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements#collect-payment), simply use the PaymentSheet instead, with the Subscription's `latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret` property. The implementation in Android should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the [subscription creation endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create). This can be done both from the mobile application and from your server.

***POST** request to `https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions` with:*

- header - you secret key;
- body: customer id and price id (you can    create new price from the
  dashboard by creating new product with    pricing).

From the response, you can get a payment intent, which can be used to pay for a subscription through a payment sheet.

**However, it is recommended to transfer the logic of working with the secret key to the server side**